# Query from All subscribers Unsubscribed last 24 hours

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I need to create a daily automation to query contacts who's status in All subscribers changed to Unsubscribed last 24 hours. 
I am totally new to query, but I tried this..

```
SELECT 
EmailAddress,
SubscriberKey,
Status,
EventDate as 'UnsubscribeDate',
FROM
_ListSubscribers 
WHERE
ListID = 305
AND
Status = 'Unsubscribed'
AND
EventDate > dateadd(hh,-24,getdate())
```

I received 'Errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.' message.
Could someone please guide me through what is wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run the below without filter DateUnsubscribed > dateadd(hh,-24,getdate())

```
SELECT 
EmailAddress,
SubscriberKey,
Status,
DateUnsubscribed as 'UnsubscribeDate'
FROM
_ListSubscribers 
WHERE
ListID = 305
AND
Status = 'Unsubscribed'
```

Once it returns the result then try running below

```
SELECT 
EmailAddress,
SubscriberKey,
Status,
DateUnsubscribed as 'UnsubscribeDate'
FROM
_ListSubscribers 
WHERE
ListID = 305
AND
Status = 'Unsubscribed'
AND
DateUnsubscribed > dateadd(hh,-24,getdate())
```

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 0):

> Errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.'

take out the `,` before from (i.e. after `'UnsubscribeDate'`)

```
SELECT 
EmailAddress,
SubscriberKey,
Status,
EventDate as 'UnsubscribeDate'
FROM
_ListSubscribers 
WHERE
ListID = 305
AND
Status = 'Unsubscribed'
AND
EventDate > dateadd(hh,-24,getdate())
```

Comment: Thank you @Data_Kid, now I have another error message...An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Invalid column name 'EventDate'.

Comment: Are data views enabled in your account?

Comment: Seems like you may need to use DateUnsubscribed instead of EventDate.

Comment: I've tried like this and it ran successfully, but returned zero records.
SELECT 
l.EmailAddress,
l.SubscriberKey,
l.Status,
u.EventDate as 'UnsubscribeDate'
FROM
[_ListSubscribers] l
JOIN
[_Unsubscribe] u
on
l.SubscriberKey = u.SubscriberKey
WHERE
l.ListID = 305
AND
l.Status = 'Unsubscribed'
AND
u.EventDate > dateadd(hh,-24,getdate())

Comment: @Chandan, do we need to enable data view?

Comment: Posted the comment as answer